# Run Python Script into Flask

Tags: python, flask

I've a desktop application to detect faces written in python script, using opencv and numpy.
i want to put these python files into flask and run it, would it run without problems? like

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

## define my functions here

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #call the functions here
    app.run()
```

would that work? if not how do i get it included? thanks!

Comment: I don't think you understand what Blueprints do. They simply organize the routes of the Flask app. They are not really useful for external functions. You can use a standard Python module for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would work, one thing you should know is if you do like below, the HTTP request won't return until after the processing is done e.g.

```
@app.route('/webcam')
def webcam_capture():
    """
    Returns a picture snapshot from the webcam
    """
    image = cv2... # call a function to get an image

    response = make_response(image) # make an HTTP response with the image
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=img.jpg'

    return response
```

Otherwise, if you put in the main function like below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # <-- No need to put things here, unless you want them to run before 
    # the app is ran (e.g. you need to initialize something)

    app.run()
```

Then your flask app won't start until the init/processing is done.

Comment: i access webcam and take a picture then process into it and return the picture? would be like take picture then return something? or do app.run() then return the result?

Comment: i know blueprints but it's used with html and css files, would it work with python ones?

Comment: `app.run()` starts your flask app, so I wouldn't put any code before it unless it is to initialize the app. To show pictures from the webcam you may e.g. use my first example using `route('/webcam')` and have that function return a picture captured from the webcam

Comment: i'm going try that , or would u suggest using blueprints? i have seen that work with html and javascript.. would it work with python files?

Comment: I'd start with a function that returns an image from the webcam, and then I'd work on a flask snippet to return a image to the browser, then tie those two together. I've modified my example to suggest a skeleton code.